# Where is the File::put() stored in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a question relating to Laravel, where is the `File::put()` stored in Laravel?

I have checked inside `storage/app/public` and the content isn't there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To store files in folder `storage/app`, you must use `Storage` class as:

```
Storage::disk('local')->put('file.txt', 'Contents');
```

then it would store a file in `storage/app/file.txt`.

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem)

Answer (score 6):

`File::put` store in `public` folder

for example .In this case file.txt will be created in public folder

```
File::put('file.txt', 'contents is written inside file.txt');
```

Also you can use Storage class

```
Storage::put( 'file.txt','contents is written inside file.txt' );
```

This will create file inside  `storage\app`

Answer (score 3):

to make sure the location you can use the functions

- public_path ()
- storage_path ()
- app_path ()

ex:

```
File::put(public_path('uploads'), $data);
```

Comment: * `File::put(config_path('someFile.ext'), $data);`. More for paths: https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can do this, and you can specify the `file_name` and the `path` of your file. Is to use [storeAs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#specifying-a-file-name)

so you will end-up with something like this

```
$file = $request->file('file');    
// Generate a file name with extension
$fileName = 'profile-'.time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();

// Save the file
$path = $file->storeAs('files', $fileName);

dd($path);
```

#output

> "files/profile-1564586486.jpg"